# How to link node objects in a data structure using templates?

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, stack

I wanted to use templates to make more general data structures for example a stack by linking node* objects. But once I used the template the node class is no longer identified, the compiler says:

**Error GCC   template class Node’ declared here
Error GCC   invalid use of template-name ‘Node’ without an argument list**

And there's my code on the header file so far:

```
#ifndef STACK_HPP
#define STACK_HPP
template <class Object>
class Node{
  friend class Stack;
  private:
    Object data;
    Node* next;
  public:
    Node(Object d);
    Node();
};
template <class Object>
class Stack{
  private:
    Node* top;
    int size;
    bool isEmpty();
  public:
    Stack();
    ~Stack();
    void Push(Object d);
    Object Pop();
    Object Spy();
};
#endif
```

Comment: If you want a stack, why don't you just use [std::stack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)? Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: `Node` isn't a type any more, and the compiler told you it needs an argument list. Like `Node<Object>`

Comment: @JesperJuhl Presumably they are just learning about data structures and templates? "Just use the standard lib version of this" is good advice in a professional setting, not so much when you want to learn how data structures are implemented.

Comment: @add a comment if it's a learning exercise, they should say so. If not, they should just use the standard library.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm doing this for study reasons

Comment: If you are going to handroll your own data structures, I recommend making `Node` into a simple `struct`. It's an implementation detail of your stack. It doesn't need a full-blown object interface with data encapsulation/information hiding. Otherwise you'll often find private node interaces turning into little more than a bunch of setters and getters which aren't even that beneficial even from the standpoint of getters/setters from the small scope (the implementation of a stack) in which they are used. There's no shame in turning an implementation detail, not exposed to the outside [...]

Comment: [...] world at large, into a simple value aggregate -- just data. It's one of the first things to learn about OOP IMO -- you don't have to make every single teeny little thing into a full-blown object. A pixel of an image does not need to be a separate object that hides and abstracts away its pixel data. A node of a tree doesn't need to hide its data. Such information hiding and abstractions cease to be helpful and start to become counter-productive at such a miniscule scope.

Comment: Easy litmus test is to ask yourself if making something into a class with separate publics and privates will just end up exposing all the privates to the outside world to tamper with, as would be the case of a `StackNode`, a `TreeNode`, a `Pixel`. If so the point of hiding away privates to maintain invariants is largely defeated anyway, by design. So those things are generally better left off as just value aggregates that don't bother to hide their data but instead turn into implementation details of something that does benefit from it, like `Stack`, `Tree`, `Image`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler will not attempt to infer what `Node` might be in your `Stack` class, it's just a *template*. You need to provide a concrete class, as in `Node<Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

Stack class is dependent upon Node class which is templated. So, wherever you declare any object of Node in Stack, you also have to provide of which type it has to be.